# How to solve the equation $x^y=y^x=k$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For a given $k>0$ constant, assuming that $x,y>0$. Also this equation has a particular name, or some mathematician associated with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WLOG suppose that $x \ge y$ and let $x = y^n$ for some $n \ge 1$.  Then (ignoring $k$) the equation becomes $y^{ny} = y^{y^n}$, or $ny = y^n$, or $y^{n-1} = n$, which gives

$\displaystyle y = n^{ \frac{1}{n-1} }, x = n^{ \frac{n}{n-1} }$.

Now it only remains to find the values of $n$ such that $x^y = k$, which you should just do numerically.  (I guess one must also account for the solutions where $x = y$; the graph $x^y = y^x$ has two components which intersect at $(e, e)$, which one gets from the above by taking the limit as $n \to 1$.)

I am almost positive this equation does not have a name because, in all honesty, it is not interesting.

Comment: Let me also mention that an alternate way to solve this equation is to write it as (log x)/x = (log y)/y.  If you graph this it's not hard to see what the solutions look like.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I remember now, sometime ago I have to study the behavior of the function $log(x)/x$ in relation to the question: which statement is valid $e^{\pi} > \pi^{e}$ or $e^{\pi} < \pi^{e}$.